Placing a label below a point in PyQGIS
I'm working on Python Console with Qgis vers. 3.36. I would place some labels below some points. I saw just in this forum other question about this issue, but I think the way how to act in this case is changed. Here is the code:

def labelGraph(layerInInput):
    labelSet  = QgsPalLayerSettings()
    text_format = QgsTextFormat()
    text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial", 12))
    text_format.setSize(10)
    labelSet.setFormat(text_format)
    labelSet.enabled = True
    labelSet.placement = Qgis.LabelPlacement.AroundPoint
    etichette = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(labelSet)
    layer_settings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(labelSet)
    layerInInput.setLabelsEnabled(True)
    layerInInput.setLabeling(etichette)
    layerInInput.triggerRepaint()

I tried, instead "AroundPoint", also "Horizontal", "OverPoint", "OrderedPositionsAroundPoint", but nothing: the result is not that I wish.

You need to use OverPoint placement and set the quadrant.
In QGIS versions >= 3.38 you can use the QgsLabelPointSettings class:
labelSet.placement = Qgis.LabelPlacement.OverPoint
lbl_pt_set = QgsLabelPointSettings()
lbl_pt_set.setQuadrant(Qgis.LabelQuadrantPosition.Below)
labelSet.setPointSettings(lbl_pt_set)

In versions < 3.38 just use the quadOffset attribute:
labelSet.placement = Qgis.LabelPlacement.OverPoint
labelSet.quadOffset = Qgis.LabelQuadrantPosition.Below

